# Prometheus counters giving wrong results

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I have a nodejs job which is using prom-client library for prometheus. I am seeing a weird behaviour in my code. My code is something like

```
let c = 0;
async batch() {
    if (c === 1000) {
         counterb.inc({ l1: 'abc' }, c);
         c = 0;
    }
}
async f() {

    const readStream = bigtable.createReadStream(...);
    for await (const row of readStream) {
       countera.inc({ l1: 'abc', l2: 'bde' });
       c++;
       batch();
    }

}
f();
```

When this job runs for millions of rows, I am getting different values of countera and counterb.

My prom query

```
countera:
sum(increase(countera[1h])) by (l1)

counterb:
sum(increase(counterb[1h])) by (l1)
```

For e.g. when counterb was 160M, countera was 130M at one instance of time. Here, countera is increasing for every row and counter for every batch.
Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the function `batch()` and concurrent access to variable `c`.

Comment: all this must be running in a single thread as nodejs's event loop is single threaded, so I believe that should not be the case. I've updated the question with labels. I forgot to add that